# Increment an element's content (an efficient one-liner?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, optimization

I got a div which I want to increment the value of. It starts with the content "1", then it should get incremented to "2", "3", etc. by JS. I want to increment it in a nice way, not like this ugly line:

```
$popup_element.parents('.plussoie').find('.vote_counter').html(parseInt($popup_element.parents('.plussoie').find('.vote_counter').html()) + 1);
```

I don't want to have any variables, and I want a one line solution. I had the beginning of a solution, but it didn't work:

```
$popup_element.parents('.plussoie').find('.vote_counter').text(parseInt($(this.html()) + 1);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baBSC/)

So can I increment a value easily, without the code soup above?

Comment: In your solution, what is `this` supposed to reference? Can you provide more of your code?

Comment: it is supposed to be the element, and $(this).html() should be 1, but is isn't the case it seems.

Comment: Also, could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: `$('.vote_counter', $popup_element.closest('.plussoie')).text(function(_, txt) { return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; });`

Comment: Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/baBSC/
I'm testing your solution adeneo, I will tell you

Comment: It works ! Thanks you
Please post an answer if you want, I will gladly accept it ;)
And could you please explain me what is this function you used ? "function(_, text)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power of [vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com):

```
element.textContent++;
```

Or, if you want you can use `.innerHTML` instead of `.textContent`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2LkY/)

Comment: Thanks you, I will maybe use it if I leave jquery one day, but I was seeking a js or jquery answer ;)

Comment: @sidney This is JS. Fully compatible with jQuery.

Comment: @sidney It doesn't require a framework. Vanilla JS is Javascript **without a framework**. (the website was a joke, note the "Final size: 0 bytes uncompressed")

Comment: Including the jQuery stuff:  `$popup_element.parents('.plussoie').find('.vote_counter')[0].textContent++`

Comment: awesome ! I feel ashamed, that is pretty incredible, I'm feeling the magic of Vanilla JS xD I will definitely check out its possibilities.